# AJAX comments box with wordpress

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

i am trying to create a comments section using Ajax in a website that uses wordpress and am trying to link it up in jQuery with a php file. i have tried every  possible way yet it does not work. please help! I always get this error:

POST http://`localhost`/ajax/comment_insert.php 404 (Not Found)

i have tried addaing slashes, removing slashes.. everything! still not working!

$(document).ready( function(){

```
$('#comment-post-btn').click( function(){

    var _comment = $('#comment-post-text').val();
    var _userId = $('#userId').val();
    var _userName = $('#userName').val();

    if (_comment.length > 0 && _userId != null ) {

        $('#comment-insert-container').css('border', '1px solid #e1e1e1');


        $.post("/ajax/comment_insert.php", {

            task: "comment_insert",
            userId: _userId,
            comment:_comment 

        },

        function( data ){

            console.log("ResponseText: " + data);

        }

    );



        console.log(_comment + "User Name: " + _userName + "User Id:" + _userId );

    } else {

        $('#comment-insert-container').css('border', '1px solid #ff0000');
        console.log("text area emopty");

    }



    //remove text from text area to insert another comment
    $('#comment-post-text').val("");

});
```

});

PHP code all what am trying to do is $_REQUEST here is the php code:

`

```
print_r($_REQUEST);
```

?>`

am running it on wamp server

Comment: It's hard to know why this is not found without having a better idea of your directory structure.

Comment: what am trying to do is a $_REQUEST thats all what comments_insert.php contains (<?php print_r ($_REQUEST); ?>) so when i try to post a comment on my comment section to test it in the console i see POST http://localhost/ajax/comment_insert.php 404 (Not Found) is the problem clear now??